# Midnight Commander closes immediately after start in Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia (KDE) via desktop menu

Tags: linux-mint, mc

Midnight Commander closes immediately after start in Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia (KDE) via desktop menu, it closes without errors, but works fine if running from terminal. A few days ago it worked well.

Don't know actually where log files stored. I watched /var/log, there is nothing related to MC, then I watched /var/crash, it is empty.

Please help, how I can see the reason of closing or run MC with logging to somewhere?

Comment: Look at this: https://youtu.be/_OPhDhK5IkM?t=112, this guy launches MC via Ubuntu's desktop menu. It opens in new window, without terminal. This is how it works for me a few days ago. Now it would not runned. I see MC icon on the task bar for a half of seconds and then it closes, no errors, nothing.